# AudioPlayer.stop - Alexa backlend with PHP

Tags: php, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

I'm trying to develope a PHP backend for my Alexa skill. Nothing big, just for learning.

What I want to do: 
I want to play some music as soon as the skill starts. I solved that the following way:

```
if ($RequestMessageType == "LaunchRequest") {
    $ReturnValue = '
    {
      "version": "1.0",
      "sessionAttributes": {},
      "response": {
        "outputSpeech": {
          "type": "PlainText",
          "text": null
        },
        "card": {
          "type": "Simple",
          "title": "Play Audio",
          "content": ""
        },
        "reprompt": {
          "outputSpeech": {
            "type": "PlainText",
            "text": null
          }
        },
        "directives": [
          {
            "type": "AudioPlayer.Play",
            "playBehavior": "REPLACE_ALL",
            "audioItem": {
              "stream": {
                "token": "33|fdd9052a-717f-414f-a438-1072a64d0f49|831",
                "url": "hereismyurl",
                "offsetInMilliseconds": 0
              }
            }
          }
        ],
        "shouldEndSession": true
      }
    }';
}
```

That works just fine.

Apart from that, I want the Skill to stop playing music if I say: "Alexa, stop". That doesn't seem to work. I tried the following:

```
if ($RequestMessageType == "AMAZON.StopIntent" ) {
    $ReturnValue = '{
        "card": {
          "type": "Simple",
          "title": "Stop Audio",
          "content": "Bla bla"
        },
        "directives": [
          {
            "type": "AudioPlayer.Stop",
          }
        ],
        "shouldEndSession": true
      } }';

} 

if ($RequestMessageType == "AMAZON.CancelIntent"){
    $ReturnValue = '{ 
        "card": {
          "type": "Simple",
          "title": "Stop Audio",
          "content": "Bla bla"
        },
        "directives": [
          {
            "type": "AudioPlayer.Stop",
          }
        ],
        "shouldEndSession": true
      } }';
}
```

I always get a "Bad Response": The skill returned an invalid response.

My SessionEndedRequest looks like the following:

```
   if ($RequestMessageType == "SessionEndedRequest") {
        $ReturnValue = '{
          "type": "SessionEndedRequest",
          "requestId": "$RequestId",
          "timestamp": "' . date("c") . '",
          "reason": "USER_INITIATED "
        }';
    }
```

Does anyone know how to stop the AudioPlayer the right way?

Comment: Hi, which php library you used for sending alexa requests and receiving from API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need to override the intent because your skill isn't active at the time of the request.  When audio is streaming and the user requests a stop, you'll get a AudioPlayer.PlaybackStopped notification event and Alexa will stop requesting your audio stream.  Handling this is optional.

From the [help page](https://developer.amazon.com/blogs/post/Tx1DSINBM8LUNHY/New-Alexa-Skills-Kit-ASK-Feature-Audio-Streaming-in-Alexa-Skills).
Sent when Alexa stops playing an audio stream in response to a voice request or an AudioPlayer directive.

You can have your own skill stop the audio with the AudioPlayer.Stop function, but the invocation process would be: Alexa, my_skillname, stop.